# Why does authorisationStatus have the same value after locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) is called?

Tags: ios, swift, location-services

I am building a navigation app which uses the iOS Core Location framework and something rather strange is going on. When I run my app `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is called which causes the alert 'Turn on Location Services to Allow "GoSiteUK" to Determine Your Location' to be displayed. In Xcode I get some contradictory information displayed when I print out `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus` to be be printed out at different points in my table view controller code. Even though I don't touch the alert my code is calling `locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization)` suggesting the Authorisation Level has been changed but clearly it isn't because I don't select anything in the alert. Can anyone suggest what is going on?
Thanks

```
   ...

 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0

        print("inside viewDidLoad() BEFORE IF authorizationStatus = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse {

            print("inside viewDidLoad() & 'if' BEFORE call: authorizationStatus = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")

            // prompts user to turn on location services
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            print("inside viewDidLoad() & 'if' AFTER call: authorizationStatus = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")
        }

        sortedCounties = countiesArray.sorted{ $0 < $1 }

   }

...

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status != .authorizedWhenInUse {

            print("inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) BEFORE call: authorizationStatus = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")
            print("inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) BEFORE call: status = \(status.rawValue)")

            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            print("inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) AFTER call: authorizationStatus = \(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)")
            print("inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) AFTER call: status = \(status.rawValue)")

        } else {

            // authorized location status when app is in use; update current location
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }

        return

    }
```

I get the following output from Xcode;

```
inside viewDidLoad() BEFORE IF authorizationStatus = 2
inside viewDidLoad() & 'if' BEFORE call: authorizationStatus = 2
inside viewDidLoad() & 'if' AFTER call: authorizationStatus = 2
inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) BEFORE call: authorizationStatus = 2
inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) BEFORE call: status = 2
inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) AFTER call: authorizationStatus = 2
inside locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization) AFTER call: status = 2
```

Comment: `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Yes it is asynchronously processed but it doesn't explain why ```locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization)``` prints out no change in the Authorization Level.

Comment: A value of `2` is "denied". Once it's been denied, it won't change unless the user changes the permission in the Settings app. And then your app will be killed and restarted.

Comment: So if it doesn't change why is ```locationManager(manager:didChangeAuthorization)``` called?

Comment: Because you called `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. The delegate is called to let you know the result.

Comment: So the delegate's method is not being called because there has been a change in the Authorisation Level? Seems contrary to its purpose??

Comment: When you set the delegate it calls the method to tell you the initial authorization status

Comment: How do you know that's what it's doing and it isn't a Core Location bug because the Apple Documentation doesn't mention that as a feature.

Comment: It might be a bug, it might be bad documentation.  You can file a bug report with apple to try and find out.

Comment: Thanks dan I think it is probably poor documentation because it kind of makes sense that it would be called for the first time with the current value than a change as it should.